# '\r' added end of the script command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
hd='pwd'
cd $hd
```

When I try to run it, it fails with:

```
line 3: cd: $'pwd\r\r': No such file or directory
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 13):

The `\r` issue suggests you have edited the script file on a Windows machine. Windows uses `\r\n` as the [line terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) while Linux (and most other operating systems) use `\n` alone. When you edit a file in Windows, Windows will add `\r` to the end of the lines and that will break your scripts.

So, first remove the `\r`:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' script.sh
```

The next issue is that your script isn't doing what you think it is. Or what I imagine you think it is, since you didn't actually say. I am guessing that you think that `hd='pwd'` sets the variable `$hd` to the value returned by the command `pwd`. That isn't what's happening. You are simply setting the variable to the *string* `pwd`:

```
$ hd='pwd'
$ echo "$hd"
pwd
```

To use the output of a command as the value for a variable, you need to use `var=$(command)` or `` var=`command` ``:

```
$ hd=$(pwd)
$ echo $hd
/home/terdon
```

So your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
hd=$(pwd)
cd "$hd"
```

In this case, however, you don't even need that. The current directory is already in a variable:

```
$ echo "$PWD"
/home/terdon
```

So you could also have done `hd=$PWD`. Or simply `cd "$PWD"`.

Comment: +1 for the very good explanation. But let me pose one question: what is the overall purpose of `cd "$PWD"`? Isn't that a no-op?

Comment: @PerlDuck that's one you should be asking of the OP, not me :) Yes, it is a no-op, I am assuming the OP wants this just to learn shell scripting and was going for a very simple command just to try things out. Note that `cd -P "$PWD"`, or even `cd -P .` can be very useful when you have arrived at a directory by following symlinks and want to see the actual path, but `cd "$PWD"` alone is indeed pointless.

Comment: @PerlDuck …unless the working directory is deleted and then recreated. I usually issue `cd .` in that case.

Comment: `dos2unix yourscriptfilename` will fix the windows lineending issue as an alternative to the sed command mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: @NGRhodes yeah, I personally never use that since the `sed` command will be available on any system and will never require installation. I don't see much reason to install an entire package when such a simple sed command will do.

Comment: dos2unix makes sense if your line endings is(are?) a mix of LF and CR+LF. Now a "sensible" user does not use Windows, so usually do not have the issue ;.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to open my `vim` file editor and execute `:set fileformat=unix`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571331/unable-to-prepare-context-path-r-not-found