# Little help with a small script

Tags: scripts

I am trying to minimize my typing with creating a few scripts, but I'm stuck.

```
echo "Creating the plex.tar.gz"
dd if=plex.bin of=plex.tar.gz bs=200 skip=1; sync
echo "I am now unpacking the plex.tar.gz"
tar -zxf plex.tar.gz
echo "It should all be done"
```

and I keep getting

```
xx:~/plex$ sudo ./plex_create
Creating the plex.tar.gz
510616+1 records in
510616+1 records out
102123230 bytes (102 MB, 97 MiB) copied, 1.43576 s, 71.1 MB/s
: not foundte: 2: ./plex_create: sync
I am now unpacking the plex.tar.gz
tar (child): plex.tar.gz\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
It should all be done
xxx@xxx:~/plex$
```

What I would require would be actually text and running command, when done, text, another command and so on.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using dd to simply copy a script? Why do you expect the bin image to unpack as a compressed archive?

Answer (score 1):

As the duplicate candidate (['\r' added end of the script command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148263/r-added-end-of-the-script-command)) states you need to remove the `\r` Windows added to the end of each line with:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' script.sh
```

You should not be using `dd` (data duplicator) to create a `.tar` (tape archive) file.

Instead of using this:

```
dd if=plex.bin of=plex.tar.gz bs=200 skip=1; sync
```

Use this instead:

```
tar -cvpzf plex.tar.gz plex.bin            # create .tar & add file
```