# Bash script - \r: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote script in bash but I have problem when I try run it by terminal. I tried on Ubuntu and Debian.

For example, this is bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
```

when I run it by this commands:

> bash name.sh

or

> . name.sh

I got that error

```
bash: $'clear\r: command not found
```

in my script I have that for every line.

Comment: Your 2nd command try should be `./name.sh`. I could not reproduce your error - do you have **clear** aliased to something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['\r' added end of the script command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148263/r-added-end-of-the-script-command)

Answer (score 4):

"`\r`" is how `bash` prints the Carriage Return character. ("`^M`,`0x0B`) that some other systems use as part of their End-of-Line marker ("`^M^J`", Carriage Return, followed by LineFeed). Linux uses only "^J" (LineFeed) at End-of-line.

One way of clearing out the "`\r`" characters is through `dos2unix`, in the package of the same name.

Another way is:

```
tr -d "\r" <name.sh >a.tmp
mv a.tmp name.sh
```