# Why doesn't chmod work in my bash script? Error is something about the directory...?

Tags: bash, chmod

Script is this:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "setpriv start"
chmod u=rwx ./ *
echo "setpriv end"
```

Output in bash window is this:

```
robertk@HP_2013:~$ bash -x setpriv
' echo 'setpriv start
setpriv start
' chmod u=rwx ./ '*
chmod: cannot access '*'$'\r': No such file or directory
' echo 'setpriv end
setpriv end
robertk@HP_2013:~$ ^C
```

????? Thanks -- something dumb / simple, I'm sure, but what???

Comment: See ['\r' added end of the script command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148263/r-added-end-of-the-script-command). Also your shebang is missing the leading `/` i.e. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Not sure if I'm supposed to use a comment to thank you, or edit my original post, but THANK YOU, steeldriver, because your comments and link fixed the problem perfectly!  I woudn't have found sed -i 's/\r//g' ... without your help.  I altered my Notepad++ to select Unix "LF" as the sole line-end character, which might help.

Comment: Yes, that was it, exactly, THANKS!  I'm a Linux newbie running Notepad++ on Win10 to edit my files, and a Ubuntu bash shell also on Win10.  I'm not a fan of nano as an editor, but I have to say that my Notepad++ would work fine for a while, then slow down to 1/100 of its normal speed.  I may have fixed this by upgrading manually from Notepad++ 7.95 to 8.1.  I'm planning on programming in C++; bash shell programming should in theory be a side effect; all suggestions are welcome.