# Move images to a seperate directory after reading their names from a file in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to read images' names from a file text which is `rgb_train_ids.txt`, and then I will move the images after reading their names to a new folder which is `Train`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(cat rgb_train_ids.txt); do 
     mv "$file.png" "Train"; 
done
```

When I execute the above bash script, it only moves the second image `img_2` and shows this:

```
mv: cannot stat 'img_1'$'\r''.png': No such file or directory
```

**I've noticed that, it always moves the last line in the file text.** 
I don't know where the problem is, could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$'\r'` indicates that the lines in your `rgb_train_ids.txt` have DOS-style line endings, consisting of the 2-character sequence CRLF. Linux expects files to use just LF. You can convert the file using the `dos2unix` utility, or strip the CR characters off using `tr` or `sed` for example.

As well, looping over lines using `for file in $(cat rgb_train_ids.txt)` is a bad practice - it will fail if the lines contain whitespace or other shell-special characters. You should consider using a `while` loop instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  mv "$file.png" Train/
done < <(tr -d '\r' < rgb_train_ids.txt)
```

The trailing `/` on `Train/` is a safety measure that will cause the `mv` command to error out if directory `Train` doesn't exist - instead of unintentionally renaming each file. Alternatively you could use `mv -t Train "$file.png"` to make it explicit that `Train` is the *target directory*.

See also

- ['\r' added end of the script command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148263/r-added-end-of-the-script-command)
- [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

You could also consider using `xargs` rather than a shell loop:

```
tr -d '\r' < rgb_train_ids.txt | xargs -d '\n' mv -t Train
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your time and efforts!